# Logical operator AND with php regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, logical-operators

I'd like to use a kind of logical operator "AND" in my regular expression.
I tried this:

```
(?=exp1)(?=exp2)
```

But in PHP `?=` doesn't work and need to write my program in PHP language. Is there another method? The expression has to match if there are present all the conditions and in any order.
I don't wanna write every permutation like:

```
(exp1)(exp2)(exp3)|(exp1)(exp3)(exp2)|....
```

Comment: I think you'll need to split the regexes

Comment: Ummm. php does support `(?=...)`: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PHP does support lookahead expressions. You're probably not using them correctly, though.

Assuming you want to match a string that contains all three of `foo`, `bar` and `baz`, you need the regex

```
^(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)(?=.*baz)
```

This will return a match for the strings `foobarbaz` or `barbazfoo` etc. However, that match will be the empty string (because the lookaheads don't consume any characters). If you want the regex to return the string itself, use

```
^(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)(?=.*baz).*
```

which will then match the entire string if it fulfills all three criteria.

I would simply use

```
if (preg_match('/^(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)(?=.*baz)/s', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Take note that this will also match a string like `foonly bartender bazooka`. If you don't want that (only allowing pure permutations of one each of the three expressions), you can do it with a little trick:

```
^(?:foo()|bar()|baz()){3}\1\2\3$
```

matches `foobarbaz`, `foobazbar`, `barfoobaz`, `barbazfoo`, `bazfoobar` and `bazbarfoo` (and nothing else). The "trick" is inspired by Jan Goyvaerts' and Steven Levithan's excellent book ["Regular Expressions Cookbook"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596520694.do) (p. 304). It works as follows:

- Each required part (`foo` etc.) is followed by an empty capturing group `()` which always matches if the required part has been matched.
- So if all three required parts have matched, all three empty capturing groups have matched.
- The following backreferences only succeed if each of the capturing groups has participated in the match.
- So if the string is `foobarbar`, the part `(?:foo()|bar()|baz()){3}` will have matched, but `\3` fails, so the overall regex fails.
- If, however, all three did take part in the match, `\1\2\3` succeeds in matching at the end of the string because each of the capturing groups contains nothing but the empty string.

Comment: @tim could you provide resources or supplementary on this?  I've never seen something like foo()|bar()|baz() before.

Comment: I guess, what I'm asking is what is the significance of the empty brackets?

Comment: @bozdoz: I added an explanation and reference.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Tim's answer:

```
(?=exp1)(?=exp2)
```

This can never be true. You say in plain english : make sure that the text followed here is exp1 and also make sure that the text followed here is exp2. No way this is true. It will never match.