# Lucene or Python: Select both "Hilary Clinton" and "Clinton, Hilary" name entries

Tags: python, regex, neo4j, lucene

Let's say I have some free form entries for names, where some are in the format "Last Name, First Name" and others are in the format "First Name Last Name" (eg "Bob MacDonald" and "MacDonald. Bob" are both present).

From what I understand, Lucene indexing does not allow for wildcards in the beginning of the sentence, so what would be some ways in which I could find both. This is for neo4j and py2neo, so solutions in either lucene pattern matching, or in python regex matching are welcome.

Comment: So...  Why not do two queries?

Comment: Because I'm building it for general use, and I want people to have a clean first look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with neo4j or lucene, but I thought I would offer a Python regex solution that I found a while ago on this question: [Logical operator AND with php regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234418/logical-operator-and-with-php-regular-expression)

Basically, you could adapt his answer to suit this particular problem: you need a first name and a last name, but you don't know the order., they might have spaces or a comma in the string.

Here's the regex I came up with: `(?:\s?Hilary()|\s?Clinton(),?){2}`

It tests for first name with an optional space in front of it, or last name with an optional space in front of it, or a comma behind it.  The empty parentheses afterwards means it will return a match if the condition is met, and the {2} means that it needs two matchs (both the first and last name).

Test it in python:

```
import re
t1 = 'Hilary Clinton'
t2 = 'Clinton, Hilary'
re.search(r'(?:\s?Hilary()|\s?Clinton(),?){2}', t1)
re.search(r'(?:\s?Hilary()|\s?Clinton(),?){2}', t2)
```

Both return a match.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use `OR`? `"Hilary Clinton" OR "Clinton, Hilary"`?

Comment: I did see that in Lucene, but it doesn't seem to work with neo4j queries. I was trying something like this: start n=node:node_auto_index("Name:Hilary Clinton" OR "Name:Clinton, Hilary") return n;

Comment: Not sure how to escape it properly, but it but you have to put the `OR` inside the quotes. Something like `"Name:'Hilary Clinton' OR Name:'Hilary Clinton'"`